# Prove the premeasure property of the measure rectangles directly

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X_1,\Sigma_1,\mu_1),~(X_2,\Sigma_2,\mu_2)$ be two $\sigma-$finite measure spaces. Because there are various definition in the literature, so let me specify the version I'm using first.

1. $E$ is called a measurable rectangle if $E=A\times B$ for some $A\in\Sigma_1$ and $B\in\Sigma_2$.
2. Define $\mu_0(E)=\sum_{k=1}^N\mu_1(A_k)\cdot\mu_2(B_k)$ for $E=\bigcup_{k=1}^N(A_k\times B_k)$.

Let $\mathcal{A}:=\{\text{all finite unions of disjoint measurable rectangles with respect to }X_1,~X_2\}$. Let $E=A\times B\in\mathcal{A}$. Suppose further that $E=\bigcup_{k}^{\infty}E_k=\bigcup_{\ell}^{\infty}(A_{\ell}\times B_{\ell})$, where $E_k\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $k=1,~2,~\cdots$ and all $E_k$ are disjoint.

I want to prove that $$\mu_0(A\times B)=\mu_1(A)\mu_2(B)=\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(A_{\ell}\times B_{\ell}).$$

I know the standard proof of it in the literature, which make use of integrals and MCT, briefly as follows:

Let $x_2\in B$, define $E^{x_2}=\{x_1\in X_1\mid (x_1,x_2)\in E\}$. So $E^{x_2}=A=\bigcup_{\ell:x_2\in B_{\ell}}A_{\ell}$.
Then $$\chi_B(x_2)\mu_1(A)=\sum_{\ell}^{\infty}\chi_{B_{\ell}}(x_2)\mu_1(A_{\ell})=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{\ell=1}^N\chi_{B_{\ell}}(x_2)\mu_1(A_{\ell})$$. Then integrate both side and use MCT we can get the result.

**My Question:** However, I think in proving such little result, the involving of the integrals and MCT are too "heavy". Because we are dealing with (pre)measure itself, why do we need to take the integrals and leave the world of measure? I didn't see there was a necessity. I think there is a simpler and more natural way, just by dealing with the $\sum$ and subscript carefully, without making any integration. But I have tried for three hours and finally failed. So I want to ask if there is a simpler way.

I think perhaps we can use double series or Cauchy series, etc.?

Comment: I am not sure I would characterise the result as little just because it does not have the bright & shiny MCT packaging.

Comment: I said this because those function that MCT are applying at are all simple functions, so I suspected there would be a simpler argument.

Comment: Many of the big theorems are basically extensions from results that are true for simple functions.